# how to get the first cell value of a hierarchy telerik grid view(MultiColumnComboBox)

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

i'm using *telerik grid view* and i want to get the first element of the child

i know how to do it for a telerik grid view  but for t's child i have no idea

it should be something like this

```
GetCustomerId = radMultiColumnComboBox1.EditorControl
                 .Rows[radMultiColumnComboBox1.SelectedIndex].Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
```

the problem is `template[0]` after dot(.) it  doesn't have `selectedindex` what should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a `GridViewTemplate` is no array, you cannot access your data using `template[0]`. Try

```
GetCustomerId = template
                 .Rows[radMultiColumnComboBox1.SelectedIndex].Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
```

or

```
GetCustomerId = radGridView1.Templates[index]
                 .Rows[radMultiColumnComboBox1.SelectedIndex].Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
```

while `index` in the second example is the index of the template you want to access in all of your templates in your `RadGridView`. If you only have one template, then it will be `.Templates[0]` for example.

**Additional note:**

In your code example `radMultiColumnComboBox1.SelectedIndex` won't have any influence to your child templates. If you want to get the first row of your template, use `.Rows[0]` instead.

Comment: Just one clarification that the SelectedIndex will have no meaning for child templates and since you need to access the first row, just use 0.